# Discord.js V.13 collect once with Collector

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm making a suggest system for my bot which starts of with the user pressing a button in a channel which then prompts them to say what they want to suggest and then their suggestion gets sent to a different channel where others can vote on it. So what I want to make it do is I want it to create a [createMessageComponentCollector](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-message-component-collector) and then register all the good/bad votes under a a period of 24h, if the suggestion got 10 good votes it's approved, otherwise it's not. Here is my code for it so far but what I'm having issue with is to start the ComponentCollector one time and then make it register the votes for each suggestion. this is the part of my code that I'm having trouble with

```js
client.channels.cache.get("909420357285474334").send({ embeds:[embed], components:[row] })

const filter1 = m => m.customId === "Yes" && i.messageId === interaction.messageId
collector1 = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({filter: filter1, time: 86400000});

const filter2 = m => m.customId === "No" && i.messageId === interaction.messageId
collector2 = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({filter: filter2, time: 86400000});

if (interaction.customId === "Yes") {
    collector1.on('collect', async i => {
        client.logger("collector1 collected")
    });

    collector1.on('end', collected => {
        client.logger(collected.size)
        // if (collected.size < 10) {

        // }
    });
}

if (interaction.customId === "No") {
    collector2.on('collect', async i => {
        client.logger("collector2 collected")
    });

    collector2.on('end', collected => {
        client.logger(collected.size)
        // if (collected.size < 10) {

        // }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please use a title which summarizes the problem. Using `Discord.js V.13` is not a good title. It's like saying "Skateboard" when the real question is how to fix a skateboard

Comment: xd sorry knew I forgot one thing ty @MrMythical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is a little bit unclear but I think I get what your looking for, if you want to check if a user already has pressed a button you could add them to a [Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set) constructor, now you need to set a `new Set()` which you can define in your startup file like this:

```
client.alreadyPressed = new Set()
```

and when you've done that one possible way to do it in your suggestion code could be like this:

```
collector1.on('collect', async i => {
    client.logger("collector1 collected")
    if (client.alreadyPressed.has(interaction.user.id)) {
        i.reply({ content: `You've already voted ${i.user.username}!`, ephemeral: true })
        return;
    } else {
        i.reply({ content: `Thank you for your vote ${i.user.username}!`, ephemeral: true });
    }
    client.alreadyPressed.add(i.user.id)
});
collector1.on('end', collected => {
    client.logger(collected.size)
    // if (collected.size < 10) {
        
    // }
});
collector2.on('collect', async i => {
    client.logger("collector2 collected")
    if (client.alreadyPressed.has(interaction.user.id)) {
        i.reply({ content: `You've already voted ${i.user.username}!`, ephemeral: true }) 
        return;
    } else {
        i.reply({ content: `Thank you for your vote ${i.user.username}!`, ephemeral: true });
    }
    client.alreadyPressed.add(i.user.id)
});
collector2.on('end', collected => {
    client.logger(collected.size)
    // if (collected.size < 10) {

    // }
});
```

one problem with this is that they only can vote once in the whole channel which im not sure if that's what you wanted

Comment: dam didn't think about that, thank you!